# Mongoose Populate users is returning a 404 (forbidden)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I am trying to populate the users array in a project but I am getting `GET http://localhost:9000/api/users 403 (Forbidden)` (if logged in) and `GET http://localhost:9000/api/users 403 (Unauthorised)` (if not logged in). So I am fairly confident that my problem is because Users have Authentication attached to them and when I am calling the list projects function.

All I am wanting to do is simply get an array of users for each project then using the objectid populate that list with the users name & profile_image.

Here is what I have:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  Project
    .find(function (err, projects) {
      if (err) { //handle error
        return handleError(res, err);
      }
      return projects;
    }) 
    .populate('users')
    .exec(function (err, projects) { 
      if (err) { //handle error
        return handleError(res, err);
      }
      return res.json(200, projects); 
    });
};
```

ProjectSchemas:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

ProjectSchema.statics = {   
  load: function (id, cb) {
    this.findOne({ _id : id })
      .populate('users', 'name profile_image')
      .exec(cb);
  }
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

UserSchema:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var crypto = require('crypto');
var authTypes = ['github', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'google'];

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    profile_image: String,
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  facebook: {},
  twitter: {},
  google: {},
  github: {}
});

/**
 * Virtuals
 */
UserSchema
  .virtual('password')
  .set(function(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function() {
    return this._password;
  });

// Public profile information
UserSchema
  .virtual('profile')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      'name': this.name,
      'role': this.role
    };
  });

// Non-sensitive info we'll be putting in the token
UserSchema
  .virtual('token')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      '_id': this._id,
      'role': this.role
    };
  });

/**
 * Validations
 */

// Validate empty email
UserSchema
  .path('email')
  .validate(function(email) {
    if (authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) !== -1) return true;
    return email.length;
  }, 'Email cannot be blank');

// Validate empty password
UserSchema
  .path('hashedPassword')
  .validate(function(hashedPassword) {
    if (authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) !== -1) return true;
    return hashedPassword.length;
  }, 'Password cannot be blank');

// Validate email is not taken
UserSchema
  .path('email')
  .validate(function(value, respond) {
    var self = this;
    this.constructor.findOne({email: value}, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(user) {
        if(self.id === user.id) return respond(true);
        return respond(false);
      }
      respond(true);
    });
}, 'The specified email address is already in use.');

var validatePresenceOf = function(value) {
  return value && value.length;
};

/**
 * Pre-save hook
 */
UserSchema
  .pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isNew) return next();

    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.hashedPassword) && authTypes.indexOf(this.provider) === -1)
      next(new Error('Invalid password'));
    else
      next();
  });

/**
 * Methods
 */
UserSchema.methods = {
  /**
   * Authenticate - check if the passwords are the same
   *
   * @param {String} plainText
   * @return {Boolean}
   * @api public
   */
  authenticate: function(plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashedPassword;
  },

  /**
   * Make salt
   *
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  makeSalt: function() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
  },

  /**
   * Encrypt password
   *
   * @param {String} password
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  encryptPassword: function(password) {
    if (!password || !this.salt) return '';
    var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
  }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I needed to make a new route for public users that didn't require authentication:

```
router.get('/public', controller.public);
```

I then added it to controller:

```
/**
 * Get public list of users
 */
exports.public = function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, 'name profileImage',function (err, users) {
    if(err) return res.send(500, err);
    res.json(200, users);
  });
};
```

Then in my state provider I resolved users to use /users/public:

```
resolve: {
  users: function(usersModel) {
    return usersModel.one('public').getList()
  }
}
```

And this has now solved the 403 error!